# Changing 'expand row' icon and its location in expandable angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I want to change the icon and location of button / icon for expanding any row in angular ui-grid. By default, the icon is plus squared and location is left most column. Any pointers for this would be appreciated.

Instead of:

[image]

I want :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fingered out the solution from Vijay's help.
Updated [plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2IqLkhyXSMkjrUa4SdwG?p=preview)

Use cell template to define a custom cell and capture the `expandable` event of `ui-grid`

`cellTemaplte` example:

```
{
     name: 'Actions',
     displayName: '',
     enableFiltering: false,
     enableColumnMenu: false,
     cellTemplate: ' <div \
    class="ui-grid-cell-contents"> \
    <i \
      ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-icon-right-dir\' : !row.isExpanded, \'ui-grid-icon-down-dir\' : row.isExpanded }" \
      ng-click="grid.api.expandable.toggleRowExpansion(row.entity)"> \
    </i> \
  </div>',
     enableSorting: false
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set below :

```
enableExpandableRowHeader: false
```

Then you need to use a custom cell template for using other icons. I have used a Font awesome icon in the plunker below. Don't forget to inject $templateCache in controller.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', "$templateCache",function ($scope, $http, $log,$templateCache) 

  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name: 'id' },
    { name: 'name'},
    { name: 'age'},
    { name: 'address.city'},
       {
    // Add a new column with your icon
    name: 'Expandable',
    displayName: '',
    enableSorting: false,
    headerCellClass: 'header-cell',
    cellClass: 'center-align',
    enableCellEdit: false,
    enableFiltering: false,
    width: '14%',
    cellTemplate: $templateCache.put('ui-grid/expandableRowHeader',
     "<div class=\'ui-grid-cell-contents expand-row\'>" +
"<i class=\'icon-margin fa fa-pencil-square-o\' " +    
    "ng-click=\'grid.api.expandable.toggleRowExpansion(row.entity)\'></i>" +
    "</div>"
)
}
```

Plunker  : http://plnkr.co/edit/7M8ZIAhHHjURkb9nSbBn?p=preview

Comment: why is `$templateCache` required here ?

Comment: Because we are creating a custom cell template .